# Runtime binding and template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

As you can see from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679525/why-are-some-functions-within-my-template-class-not-getting-compiled) not all template functions are being compiled in a template class. Standard says, that if the method or a member is not being used, it is not being compiled. Cool feature, indeed! Now, lets discuss the following hierarchy:

```
class A
{
  virtual void f() {};
};

template <typename T>
class B : public A
{
  virtual void f () override
  {
       // do something dangerous
  }
}
```

You will never know if `B<int>::f` is being called, right? The reason is that you can call a function `B::f` with dynamic binding and you never know if `A*` points onto `B` type object or other typed object that is derived from `A`. So how the compiler should handle this case?

```
A* ptr = nullptr;
if (i > 0)
{
    ptr = new B<int>();
}
ptr->f();
```

How does compiler guess/spot this case to generate `B<int>::f`

**IMPORTANT RELATED QUESTION:**
[Can a C++ class member function template be virtual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354210/can-a-member-function-template-be-virtual)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your program you have to use `B<int>` or a type derived there of to create an instance. At that point the template is instantiated and the code for it is generated. There is also explicit instantiation. Check out [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template) for details.

Comment: Kurt, I have wrote `new B<int>()`, hence it know that for `int` the code should be generated, but the question is how does it know that I am going to use `B::f`?

Comment: Because it's a virtual function. The compiler has to generate the virtual functions for an instantiated type because it cannot know if it is called or not in general.

Comment: Your comment is the answer. So for template class all virtual functions are generated.