# Why this code works (C++ template class with invalid non-template function)?

Tags: c++, templates

This C++ code builds successfully:

```
void h(int *)
{
}

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    void f()
    {
        T *val;
        
        h(val);
    }
};

int main()
{
    A<const int> a;
}
```

Why?

It is undeniable that `A<const int>::f()` cannot work.

If you call `a.f()`, it fails to build as expected.

Why is an instance of `A<const int>` even allowed to exist then?

I'm not sure how SFINAE applies here.

I'd appreciate a C++ standard quote or a relevant link.

Comment: Have you tried compiling an actual call of `a.f()`? (Hint: it won't go so well: https://ideone.com/geyI0b)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are some functions within my template class not getting compiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679525/why-are-some-functions-within-my-template-class-not-getting-compiled)

Comment: The member function is not instantiated unless you use it, and there is no problem if you don't.

Comment: @scohe001 "_Have you tried compiling an actual call of `a.f()`?_" They already answered such question: "_If you call `a.f()`, it fails to build as expected._"

Comment: Its not A's fault, its h's fault.

Comment: Nothing about this looks like SFINAE.

Comment: @scohe001 That's the whole point of my question. Also, I wrote it: _If you call `a.f()`, it fails to build as expected._

Comment: actually it is very desriable that your code does compile. Its a feature that makes templates more generic (even without SFINAE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no sfinae here. If we look closely at the declaration of the function, and not it's implementation:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    void f();
};
```

You can see that there's nothing to tell the compiler that this function should not be part of overload resolution.

If we add a return type containing an expression, this is different:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    auto f() -> decltype(void(h(std::declval<T*>())));
};
```

That's different. Now The compiler need to resolve `h(T*)` to perform overload resolution. If the substitution fails (the instantiation of the function declaration) then the function is not part of the set.

---

As for why the code still compiles, take a look at this:

```
void h(int *)
{
}

template <typename T>
class A
{};

template<typename T>
void f()
{
    T *val;
        
    h(val);
}


int main()
{
    A<const int> a;
}
```

1. It's undeniable that `f(A<const int>)` cannot work
2. If you call `f(a)`, it fails to build as expected.
3. Why is an instance of `A<const int>` even allowed to exist then?

The answer should become obvious now: the function is never instantiated!

The very same applies for member functions. There is no use to instantiate all member function if you don't use them.

---

If you look for an official statement that comfirm this behavior, then look no further than the standard itself.

From [[temp.inst]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#4) (emphasis mine):

> Unless a member of a class template or a member template is a declared specialization, **the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist** or if the existence of the definition of the member affects the semantics of the program; in particular, the initialization (and any associated side effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the definition of the static data member to exist.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot Guillaume. I'm going to accept this one as it's very complete and answers my question.

Answer (score 6):

It's allowed to exist because it can still be useful for it to exist.

Consider `std::vector`, which has a one-argument overload of `resize`, which default-constructs new elements. Definitely useful! But it's also useful to have a `std::vector` of some type which isn't default-constructible, when you don't intend to resize it in that way. Forcing all member functions to be available, even those not needed by the user, would artificially restrict the applicability of a class.

Comment: I understand that it's a nice language feature, and in fact I need it, so I'm glad it exists. I'm just looking for an official statement which confirms that this is expected behaviour.

Comment: @eepp - In that case, your question is answered by the suggested duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679525/why-are-some-functions-within-my-template-class-not-getting-compiled